# Eclipse (Android) IDE error

Tags: android, eclipse

I get an error like below when running all projects in eclipse IDE, but in individual files(XML or JAVA), there are no errors specified.

```
[2011-11-21 10:42:34 - aaa] product variants
[2011-11-21 10:42:34 - aaa] --utf16
[2011-11-21 10:42:34 - aaa] changes default encoding for resources to UTF-16.  Only useful when API
[2011-11-21 10:42:34 - aaa] level is set to 7 or higher where the default encoding is UTF-8.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was getting this, This means your "Platform Tool" package is out of date. Please update it using the SDK Manager.

I think problem related to eclipse version or android ADT. then try reinstall a newest version Eclipse.

maybe this link help to you: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998413/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-in-android-4/8205792#8205792) - [link2](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21584)

Answer (score 3):

on your files change the utf coding to 8 at the top.  In the xml files it says "encoding=" edit that to say 8.

Comment: yes...i changed...........but still the problem is persuing with....any other sugegstions???

Comment: it might be an error with the new updates, i am having a large number of problems with the new ADT 14

Comment: delete eclipse and reinstall clean making sure the plugins work.

Comment: Update from helios to Indigo, then update your plugins it should work fine now.  ADT 15 works great and is fixed, just make sure you download and use Indigo