# Android Dex: trouble processing "javax/transaction/xa/XAException.class":

Tags: build, intellij-idea, android-studio

I am trying to build my project in the new Android Studio IDE and am unable to. I get this error but I cannot find where this class is being used.

I found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-platform/abxNKTFkuj8

According to that page it is caused by the IDE trying to build the android.jar library. However I can't find a reference to it n my *Project Structure* dialog.

[Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 in Android 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998413/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-in-android-4)

None of my classes start with the java.* prefix.

This is my project lib view:
[image: Libs view in Android Studio]

It seems as though something is different with Android Studio, my project builds fine with both Ant and Eclipse.

Comment: I'm suffering a similar problem at the minute - di you find a solution?

Comment: @MattWhetton I haven't had a chance to look at it again. I've reverted to Eclipse for the time being and my build is working fine there.

Comment: @MattWhetton have you tried with the latest version? This question is worth looking at too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099291/intellij-android-support-v4-jar-in-included-in-actionbarsherlock-and-project

Comment: Yes thanks - android studio seems a lot more solid now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to ActionBarSherlock being built and using the support-v4 library too. The solution was to change the dependencies in the Library settings in Android Studio. Since I was already including ActionBarSherlock as a jar I just excluded it from being built at all.

This question helped: [Intellij: android-support-v4.jar in included in actionBarSherlock and Project => IllegalArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099291/intellij-android-support-v4-jar-in-included-in-actionbarsherlock-and-project)